# jackson serializing Collections.unmodifiable*

Tags: java, json, serialization, collections, jackson

I have a problem using the Jackson serialization from json, how do I serialize from `Collections.unmodifiableMap?`

The error I get is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap, problem: No default constructor found
```

I wanted to use the `SimpleAbstractTypeResolver` from http://wiki.fasterxml.com/SimpleAbstractTypeResolver however I cannot get the inner class type `Collections$UnmodifiableMap`

```
Map<Integer, String> emailMap = newHashMap();
Account testAccount = new Account();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY);
String marshalled ;
emailMap.put(Integer.valueOf(10), "bob@mail.com");
testAccount.setMemberEmails(emailMap);

marshalled = mapper.writeValueAsString(testAccount);
System.out.println(marshalled);
Account returnedAccount = mapper.readValue(marshalled, Account.class);
System.out.println(returnedAccount.containsValue("bob@mail.com"));


public class Account {
  private Map<Integer, String> memberEmails = Maps.newHashMap();

  public void setMemberEmails(Map<Integer, String> memberEmails) {
    this.memberEmails = memberEmails;
  }

  public Map<Integer, String> getMemberEmails() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(memberEmails);
  }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you've run into an edge-ish type case with Jackson. The problem really is that the library will happily use your getter method to retrieve collection and map properties, and only falls back to instantiating these collections/maps if those getter methods return null.

This can fixed by a combination of `@JsonProperty/@JsonIgnore` annotations, with the caveat that the `@class` property in your JSON output will change.

Code example:

```
public class Account {
    @JsonProperty("memberEmails")
    private Map<Integer, String> memberEmails = Maps.newHashMap();

    public Account() {
        super();
    }

    public void setMemberEmails(Map<Integer, String> memberEmails) {
        this.memberEmails = memberEmails;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Map<Integer, String> getMemberEmails() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(memberEmails);
    }
}
```

If you serialize this class with your test code you will get the following JSON:

```
{
    "@class": "misc.stack.pojo.Account",
    "memberEmails": {
        "10": "bob@mail.com",
        "@class": "java.util.HashMap"
    }
}
```

Which will deserialize correctly.

Comment: Thanks Perception. This works perfectly for my purposes. Is there a way to have the same behaviour without falling back to annotations on the model class itself?

Comment: @hartraft what you might want to use are Jackson Mix In's http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

The first thing Jackson looks for is the default constructor. If you want to use a different constructor, you need to specify add `@JsonCreator` on it and `@JsonProperty` annotations on its parameters.

Since you don't have ability to add these annotations to `Collections.UnmodifiableCollection` you won't be able to deserialize it.

1. You probably don't need to to use unmodifiable collection to be serialized. What is the point? You can do that when deserializing the object. Also deserialized object will be different from the one serialized (copy)
2. If you really need that, you can simply write your own `UnmodifiableCollection` class. It is very simple, since it is just a wrapper of collection and delegates method invocations to the underlying collection

   ```
   public boolean isEmpty() { return c.isEmpty(); } // c is underlying collection
   ```

   except for modifying methods:

   ```
   public boolean add(E e) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }
   .....
   ```
3. You could also call one of the methods before serialization to serialize array. When deserializing build you model object with creating collection from array and access this collection with getter returning unmodifiable collection:

   ```
   public Object[] toArray();
   public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
   ```
4. You can add `@JsonIgnore` to your getter method in model and add `@JsonValue` to your `memberEmails` field.
5. You can create another getter (private and with different name) and annotate it as `@JsonValue` for your field

Comment: Thanks Tala! i looked into the example i put into the original question and this indeed doesnt have a problem serializing unmodifiableMap

The ObjectMapper i have uses DefaultTyping which is causing my issue. I've updated the question and I can narrow my search criteria a bit further now

Comment: I've added options 4 and 5. I would personally go with 4